# How do I type a backtick in RubyMine with a Swedish keyboard layout?

Tags: java, keyboard-layout

I can type a backtick just fine in any application save [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) (and probably any stupid JVM app) either by pressing `S-Backtick S-Backtick` (i.e. pressing Backtick twice whilst holding down Shift), or by pressing `S-Backtick Space`.

Any clues what could be going on here? It almost certainly has to be Java, but I don't know anything about adjusting Java input settings or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu the backtick key is a modifier key for extended characters:  backtick+e = è etc.  Two backticks give a backtick by itself.

It is quite likely the Java application isn't interpreting the double-character keyboard input as a whole but taking each character separately.

You may find it necessary to create a custom keyboard map (or modify the Swedish one).  I'm not sure how you'd go about that in Ubuntu.

Comment: Hrm, maybe I should file a bug with RubyMine.